# How to Replicate one Object from Another Object? How to create bulk filed in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce-to-salesforce

I have a requirement to replicate Account object from one org to another Org's Custom object.
I want to check all the properties which are defined for Account Object.
Few of them are visible on Detail page but things like Enable Chatter and allow search are not mentioned anywhere. Also Name field for Account is of Name Datatype but for Custom object we have only Text or Auto Number option.
Can someone tell me how to get all these details and mapping?

Also is there any way to create bulk Object from spreadsheet (other than bulk object creator tool as it requires everything to be done manually after creating basic fields. It does not even give the flexibility to choose different filed size and we have to select field type manually)? I need to create Custom object with 300+ fields which is replica of Account object from other org. This is needed as part of Org merge.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Shuchi

Comment: If all the metadata is already present in other org, I think retrieving the (xml) using metadata api and deploying in your org can help and then do data migration.

Comment: Thanks Elijah, are you suggesting use of ANT or some other deployment tools to retrieve the object metadata and deploy it to target org ?

Comment: Yep you can use ANT or you could just retrieve all the definition of your Object using VS code and deploy it. Just remember you will have to take care of profile permissions or permission sets separately.